# Mongoose ODM: Can't save encoded password because of async

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

I have the problem that the salt generation and password encoding is are ready when the document gets already persisted. => mongoosejs doesn't wait until the hashing is finished, so we have no passwords and salts in database (but I can console.log them :).

Is there something to avoid this behaviour?

1. A waiter function?
2. Or should I move the encoding part into some pre-save middleware?

**encoding method**

```
UserSchema.methods.encodePassword = function(password) {
    crypto.randomBytes(32, function(err, buf) {
        this.salt = buf.toString('hex');
        console.log(this.salt);
        crypto.pbkdf2(password, this.salt, 25000, 512, function(err, encodedPassword) {
            if (err) throw err;
            this.password = encodedPassword;
            console.log(this.password);
        }.bind(this));
    });
};
```

**route action**

```
// creates a new user
app.post('/users', function(req, res) {
    // create new user
    var user = new User();
    // assign post
    user.username = req.body.username;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.encodePassword(req.body.password);
    user.save(function(err, user) {
        console.log(user);
        if (!err) return res.send(err, 500);
        return res.json(user);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want `encodePassword` to take a callback so you can call it when you're done.

```
UserSchema.methods.encodePassword = function(password, callback) {
    crypto.randomBytes(32, function(err, buf) {
        this.salt = buf.toString('hex');
        console.log(this.salt);
        crypto.pbkdf2(password, this.salt, 25000, 512, function(err, encodedPassword) {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            this.password = encodedPassword;
            console.log(this.password);
            callback();
        }.bind(this));
    });
};
```

Now you can wait for it to be done in your route.

```
app.post('/users', function(req, res) {
    // create new user
    var user = new User();
    // assign post
    user.username = req.body.username;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.encodePassword(req.body.password, function(err) {
        if(err) { /* handle error */ }
        user.save(function(err, user) {
            console.log(user);
            if (!err) return res.send(err, 500);
            return res.json(user);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey, for some reason this still don't works. I assume that UserSchema.methods.encodePassword doesn't has semantical access to the  model. I will check this out

Comment: I will ask at the mongoose google groups. The docs are way to minimalistic. I never know when and how I can access model properties through setters, methods, plugins, however